# How to orthogonalize polynomials?

Tags: integration, orthogonal-polynomials

Consider the   infinite series of polynomials $e_0(x), e_1(x), e_2(x), \ldots $ where $e_n(x)=x^n-1.$ I want  to orthogonalise them, so I am looking for the range  $[a,b]$   and for a weight function $w(x)$ such that 
$$
\int_a^b e_n(x) e_m(x) w(x)=\delta_{n,m}
$$
I have tried to search for $w(x)$  as a polynomial and as  series    but not  with  any  success. Any ideas?

Comment: By "orthogonalize," you mean to find a weighted space such that they are orthogonal? Usually this means to pick some space and then to change $e_{n}$ to $\tilde{e}_{n}$, where $\mathrm{span}(e_{0},\ldots,e_{n})=\mathrm{span}(\tilde{e}_{0},\ldots,\tilde{e}_{n})$ for all $n\geq 0,$ for instance, by the Gram-Schmidt procedure.

Comment: Also, should $e_{0}=1$?

Comment: Are you sure that the upper limit is $n$ instead of $b$?

Comment: Corrected, of course, $b$

Comment: It is infinite series so I cant apply the Gram-Schmidt procedure.I am looking for the weight function $w(x)$

Comment: You could approximate it with linear least squares and sums instead of integrals. If you are OK with that. Or do you need an analytic expression in """elementary""" functions?

Comment: Given a weight function and range you can certainly apply Gram-Schmidt.  You just start from the lowest degree and orthogonalize your way up.  They won't have the form $x^n-1$ any more because you will subtract off terms proportional to the lower polynomials.

Comment: @mathreadler  I need an analytic expression for  $w(x).$

Comment: Since $x^n-1$ is so well behaved, I would do it as a linearly expressed finite difference least squares problem fused to a linear combination of basis functions, for example a truncated power series or a FFT. But maybe not everyone would be comfortable doing that.

Comment: This is more or less a [Moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem)